# How long can I keep EBS snapshots?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a need to keep EBS snapshots for 7 years for regulatory purposes.

AWS documentation says:

You can retain snapshots based on either the total count of snapshots or the age of each snapshot.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html

However, it does not give a maximum of age.

Can I keep EBS snapshot for 7 years?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Retain**–You can retain snapshots based on either the total count of snapshots or the age of each snapshot. For retention based on the count, the range is 1 to 1000. After the maximum count is reached, the oldest snapshot is deleted when a new one is created. **For age-based retention, the range is 1 day to 100 years.** After the retention period of each snapshot expires, it is deleted. The retention period should be greater than or equal to the creation interval. *(emphasis added)*
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshot-lifecycle.html#dlm-elements

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!